# How to represent an ARIMA(p,d,q) with dlm package in R?

Tags: r

I've been using [DLM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/index.html) package for modeling my timeseries in state-space format, and then use Kalman Filter to get better 2 step-ahead forecasts.

Even though I've read the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlm/dlm.pdf) and parts of [their book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387772375), I'm still struggling when it comes to modeling my ARIMA process in state-space format, specifically as the dlm package understands it. My plan is to use **auto.arima()** to get the best arima model, then represent it as a dlm.

I've seen examples like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/66156/42176).

```
# Estimation of a state space representation of Arima(1,1,1) model and forecast:
level0 <- data.s.g[1]
slope0 <- mean(diff(data.s.g))
buildGap <- function(u) {
trend <- dlmModPoly(dV = 1e-7, dW = exp(u[1 : 2]),
                  m0 = c(level0, slope0),
                  C0 = 2 * diag(2))
gap <- dlmModARMA(ar = ARtransPars(u[4]),ma=u[5], sigma2 = exp(u[3]))
return(trend + gap)}
```

and the dlmModARMA part seems clear. What is baffling me is, what to do if I want to get for example ARIMA(1,3,1); how would I represent that 3 differencing part?